# Firing event onChange on dropdown with one option

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've created a scripts that makes requests to the server and gets a json response with some data that is used to create dropdown dinamically, in some cases the server returns one single value and, of course, the dropdown generated has only one option (as follow)

```
<div id="wrap">
    <select class="click_me">
        <option value="1">foo</option> --> this value comes from a json response.
    </select>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery script (I think that it is self explanatory)

```
$('#wrap').on('change', 'select', function() {

    var container = $('#wrap');
    var self = $(this);
    self.nextAll().remove();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'server/stuff?id=' + self.val(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
          var options = self.clone().empty().appendTo(container); //clone current dropdown.
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $.each(value, function(key, value) {
              options.append($("<option />").val(key).text(value)); //fill cloned element with new data
            });
          });
        } else {
          console.log('Nothing more');
        }
      }
    });


  });
```

If user gets a dropdown with one option, the script above doesn't work. I think that event onchange is not triggered at all, I tried onclick event but it fires when user just want to open the dropdown.

Please, any advice is appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You loading the data to the dropdown from json response. then the user should select one option from the dropdown then u change it further. In that case why you need automation when there is only one option?

Comment: Is my answer useful to you?

Comment: Sandiip Patil: the dropdowns represents data stored hierarchically (country > state > city > training centers) inside a state could exist only one city but in that city could exist many training centers) and that's the problem that I explained in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a workaround for this like the following way. When clicking on the select list and if it has only one option we can call the change event by our self. So try

```
$('#wrap').on('change', 'select', function() {
  //your stuff 
}).click(function(){
   if($('#wrap select option').length == 1) {
    $('#wrap select').change();
  }
});
```

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DuLUy/). Test it by adding some more options to dropdown to ensure that, it is also working for more than one options.

Answer (score 0):

after your `json response` make a check like this:

```
if($('#wrap .click_me option').length == 1) {
    $('#wrap .click_me').change();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$("dropdownId").blur(function(){
// here goes your code
}
```