# Jquery change() dont work on select box when contain only one item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a dynamic select box with php and jquery, i have 4 select boxes, the content of the first one is loaded in the page load.

When i choose one of the items in the first select box, the seconde one get data from database related to the first select box...and so on

But the problem is : when the select box contain only one item, the `change()` function of jquery doesn't work `$('#MySelectId').change(function(){ //......});`

[image: Dynamic Dependent Select Box Using jQuery and Ajax]

Any suggestions ?

I'm working with PHP, jQuery v1.6.4 and jQuery Chosen Plugin.

Comment: i suggest you to add an initial option tag to your select box as placeholder. so never will be only one option at your select box.

Comment: If it contains only one item, nothing is changing because that one item is already selected. In that case you should manually trigger the change event if there is only one item (also pre-populate the field)

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851365/firing-event-onchange-on-dropdown-with-one-option

Comment: As ou know, i use the selected item to load the next select box, should i then check if the user didn't select the value of the placeholder ?

Comment: i add <select id="mabranche" data-placeholder="Choisissez la branche"> it appear "Choisissez la branche" as an initial value but still not working!!

Answer (score 1):

If your select box only contains 1 item this item is already selected so if you select it again the value doesn't change so no change event is fired. Add a placeholder like "Please select item" or something which is selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$('#MySelectId').on('change', 'select', function() {
  alert('changed');
  }).click(function(){
      if($('#MySelectId select option').length == 1) {
      $('#MySelectId select').change();
      }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuLUy/6/)

or you can try with jquery bind if you are not using 1.7.x + version.

```
$('#MySelectId').bind('change', function() {
  alert('changed');
}).click(function(){
   if($('#MySelectId select option').length == 1) {
    $('#MySelectId select').change();
}
});
```

[test here](http://jsfiddle.net/DuLUy/7/)

[check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851365/firing-event-onchange-on-dropdown-with-one-option) this post also

Comment: I doesn't work, i wanna add something; MySelectId is the id of the <select> tag and im using jQuery v1.6.4

Comment: try with jquery 'bind' or 'live' instead of 'on'

Comment: It work now with 'live', but why alert('changed'); is executed two times ?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DuLUy/8/  here it is being called once , in your case you might calling the function twice where you put this code.

Comment: it work, but it keep the same behaviour (the alert is executed two times. The first, when i open the select box(when contain only one item but work fine in other cases) and when i choose the item it executed again).